# New command not working as expected

Tags: macros

When using `\fbox` on its own, it creates a border around the text. However, I want to create a new command so I can create a boxed code example. Written 'inline', it works as expected:

```
\fbox{\scriptsize{\texttt{example}}}
```

However, when I put it into a new command:

```
\newcommand{codelist}[1]{\fbox{\scriptsize{\texttt{#1}}}
```

It doesn't apply the border, nor does it apply the font and sizing.

I am completely new to LaTeX, so any help will be much appreciated in identifying what the problem is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
\newcommand{\codelist}[1]{\fbox{\scriptsize{\texttt{#1}}}
```

You missed a backslash.

**EDIT**

As Herbert pointed out in his answer, a couple of the curly braces are not required, since `\scriptsize` is a switch and takes no arguments. i.e.

```
\newcommand{\codelist}[1]{\fbox{\scriptsize\texttt{#1}}
```

is sufficient since the script sized text is contained within the scope of `fbox`.

Comment: That worked, thank you. I assumed the slash was implicit. Will accept answer once it lets me.

Comment: @SaladinAkara: You're welcome. It seemed strange to me too the first time!

Comment: As pointed out by Herbert, the curly brackets to the right of `\scriptsize` don't do anything since it's a switch. The `\fbox` is really what is containing it, and in general you'd want to do it like this: `{\scriptsize stuff}`.

Answer (score 4):

use it this way:

```
\newcommand\codelist[1]{\fbox{\scriptsize\texttt{#1}}
```

`\scriptsize` is a switch and not a command with an argument. 
A command has to befined *with* a backslash and an environment by its name *without* a backslash:

```
\newcommand\foo[..]{...}
\newenvironment{foo}[...]
  {...}
  {...}
```